# Not Equals Operator not working when interrupts are enabled on PIC32

Tags: c, embedded, uart, mplab, pic32

I am currently trying to parse a string received via UART from a GPS module on a PIC32MZ2048EFG100 micro-controller via a UART receive interrupt protocol. I am using MPLAB X IDE v4.10 and XC32 v2.05 for my IDE and compiler.

When I enabled the UART4 receive interrupt, the != operator stops functioning as it should. I have a block of code within my main function that should never be executed, but yet it is.

I have narrowed it down to enabling interrupts being the problem. If I comment out all working code in my ISR, I still face the issue of myCounter being incremented.

Here is the code I have in my main function.

```
int myCounter = 0;

void main ( void ){

    hal_sys_init();
    hal_uart4_init();
    gps_init();

    //Setup interrupt
    asm volatile("di"); //Disable all interrupts
    asm volatile("ehb"); //Disable all interrupts

    INTCON = 0; //Clear interrupt control register

    IEC0 = 0;
    IEC1 = 0;
    IEC2 = 0;
    IEC3 = 0;
    IEC4 = 0;
    IEC5 = 0;
    IEC6 = 0;

    INTCONbits.MVEC = 1; //Enable multi-vectored interrupts

    IFS5bits.U4RXIF = 0; //Clear interrupt flag
    IPC42bits.U4RXIP = 1; //Set priority level to 7
    IPC42bits.U4RXIS = 0; //Set sub-priority to 0
    IEC5bits.U4RXIE = 1; //Enable interrupt

    asm volatile("ei"); //Enable all interrupts

    while(1){
        int x = 0;
        if(x != 0){
            myCounter++;  //Should never be executed
        }
    }
}
```

When running this code on my PIC with interrupts enabled, myCounter gets incremented. [image: myCounter has a value of 0x275 after running for a few seconds]

Here is the code for my interrupt service routine.

```
void __ISR(_UART4_RX_VECTOR, ipl7SRS) UART4_Interrupt(void) {
    while (U4STAbits.URXDA) {
        char c = U4RXREG;
        if (c == '\n') {
            currentLine[--lineIndex] = 0; //Overwrite /r as null terminator for string
            parseStringFlag = 1;
            lineIndex = 0;

            if (currentLine == buff_1) {
                currentLine = buff_2;
                previousLine = buff_1;
            } else {
                currentLine = buff_1;
                previousLine = buff_2;
            }

        } else if (lineIndex < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
            currentLine[lineIndex++] = c;
        } else {
            currentLine[--lineIndex] = c;
        }
    }
    IFS5bits.U4RXIF = 0; //Clear interrupt flag
    return;
}
```

Here is the basic ISR code that still makes myCounter increment.

```
void __ISR(_UART4_RX_VECTOR, ipl7SRS) UART4_Interrupt(void) {
    while (U4STAbits.URXDA) {
        char c = U4RXREG;
    }
    IFS5bits.U4RXIF = 0; //Clear interrupt flag
    return;
}
```

What could be causing the code that should never be executed to execute? If I run the interrupt code in main with interrupts disabled the code works and the code that should never be executed is not executed.

Comment: The code in main looks indeed like it should not increment x. I am afraid you are looking at something evil, stackoverflow, wild pointer, UB, ... Good luck (no sarcasm intended).

Comment: You might want to upgrade your code quote to a [mcve]. I am missing the declaration and definition of `lineIndex` and `currentLine`; without this `currentLine[--lineIndex] = 0;` looks fishy.

Comment: Please take the [tour] at your convenience.

Comment: Looks fishy, because with a corrupted `lineIndex` below 0, this one could write something other than 0 to x `currentLine[--lineIndex] = c;`.

Comment: @Yunnosch : Need not be "corrupted" as such - if the first character received were `\n`, it would be decremented from zero.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have updated my question to include a more minimal ISR that still gives me the same error without needing the `currentLine` or `lineIndex` variables.

Comment: @Clifford Without meaning to contradict you, my meaning is that anything which is used as an array index is corrupted (for that purpose) if <0.

Comment: @Yunnosch : I appreciate that, but there is a clear and useful distinction between explicitly but erroneously assigning a value, and a value being changed indirectly. From that distinction, the index is incorrectly assigned rather than corrupted, whilst any subsequent write to the array via the incorrect index, will corrupt whatever it resolves to.  I say the distinction is useful, because invalid assignment is a predictable semantic error, you can determine where and when it will happen, and can reproduce it reliably.  Corruption on the other hand leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Clifford I agree. Using "corrupted" as I did was misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
    if (c == '\n') {
        currentLine[--lineIndex] = 0; //Overwrite /r as null terminator for string
```

If the first character received were `\n` and `lineIndex` is initialised zero, `lineIndex` will be decremeted from zero.  Assuming it is unsigned, then `lineIndex < MAX_LINE_LENGTH` will be false and:

```
    } else {
        currentLine[--lineIndex] = c;
    }
```

will run repeatedly until `lineIndex` is eventually decremented to `MAX_LINE_LENGTH - 1` - stomping over a large swathe of memory - which is most likely what is happening in this case.

Suggest:

```
    if( lineIndex != 0 && c == '\n' && ) 
    {
        currentLine[--lineIndex] = 0; //Overwrite /r as null terminator for
```

or:

```
    if( c == '\n' ) 
    {
        if( lineIndex != 0 ) 
        {
            lineindex-- ;
        }
        currentLine[lineIndex] = 0; //Overwrite /r as null terminator for
```

depending on the semantics you require.  It is not a given that the sending system uses CR+LF pairs for line-ends, and you should not assume that. The code should probably be further modified to check that the preceding character was indeed a CR before decrementing `lineindex`.  An exercise for the reader.

And similarly for the final else:

```
    } 
    else if( lineIndex != 0 )
    {
        currentLine[--lineIndex] = c;
    }
```

or

```
    } 
    else
    {
        if( lineIndex != 0 ) 
        {
            lineindex-- ;
        }
        currentLine[lineIndex] = c;
    }
```

It is possible that the latter protection is not necessary, but the protection is useful perhaps for clarity and maintenance - it is *defensive code* - your call.

It may be a safer and more interrupt efficient design to have the ISR simply place any received character into a ring-buffer, and then deal with line-input outside of the interrupt context.  You might increment a counter on every received `\n` and decrement it when `\n` were unbuffered so that the receiver will know how many lines are currently buffered for processing.

Comment: I updated and added some information to my question. I certainly will need to fix the issue you have pointed out, but unfortunately it is not the root cause of an unreachable code block being executed, as I can run the more simplified ISR now posted in the question and get the same results.

Comment: @K.Crow : If you have the necessary debug tools, set a data access breakpoint on the variable  x to see what is writing to it.  Failing that make it static to move it off the stack, and see what happens.  If it is no longer corrupted, then it is a stack error.  Do you have other interrupts active?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue just now. It seems that I had not configured the interrupt to use the shadow register set, and so changing `IPL7SRS` to `IPL7SOFT` fixed the issue. It seems that attempting to use the shadow register set without proper configuration was causing the issue.